# Firefox not allowing SOCKS proxy

Tags: firefox, proxy, socks5

I used to be able to configure a SOCKS proxy in firefox (either v4 or v5), but now the host input element is completely not accepting user input.  It is not disabled, but whatever I type is not getting entered into the field?

This should work out of the box, right?

[image]

Comment: It is supposed to work right out of the box to input your host there.  If it is not allowing input even after a clean install of Firefox, you might be experiencing a bug with Firefox.  Bugs for Firefox would be filed at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/home

Comment: did you made any changes to files rights? if so you would have to fix files perms on `~/.mozilla/firefox` FYI, proxy settings are stored in `~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile.default>/prefs.js`

Comment: I run firefox as another group, via sg, but the permissions are allowing that group write access.  I didn't see anything in dmesg -Tw or journalctl -f.